# Unit testing text manipulation in the DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I am trying to test simple DOM manipulation and running into some trouble. Imagine the following simple click event:

```
$('.js-click-me').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.some-span').text('changed text');
});
```

Now also imagine that my HTML contains the following:

```
<span class="some-span">Original Text</span>
<button class="js-click-me">Click Me</button>
```

Ok, so now I have a unit tests

```
describe('text change test', function() {
  it('The text of .some-span should change when button is clicked', function() {
    assert.equal('Original Text', $('.some-span').text());
    $('.js-click-me').click();
    assert.equal('changed text', $('.some-span').text());
  });
});
```

My expectation is that the first assertion will pass because the original text is, in fact "Original Text" (this is just done to set a baseline and probably not required).

The second assertion I expect to pass because after the click it is changing the text from "Original Text" to "changed text". However, when I run tests like this the second assertion fails because the test runs *immediately* after and the DOM hasn't updated the text yet.

I can add the second test in a `setTimeout` wrapper but that doesn't seem correct or efficient.

Any tips for this?

Comment: I want to note that "click" is just a simple example. I want to test every possible way that text might change, including part of a function that is called.

Comment: An event generated by calling `$(..).click()` is handled synchronously. Have you done a manual check that your DOM has in fact been changed but your test just fails to pick it up?

Comment: Yes. It's not always a click event I'm using to trigger this DOM change. If I alert out the text value it's correct.  I think ones that don't use .find() and .children() are more performant and so they change without delay and those that do require a timeout.

Comment: As an example right now I'm testing function output, so I call a function with some data and then the function changes the text of certain DOM elements based on that data. The function works, the text change happens, but not immediately.

Answer (score 0):

use .**then** function. Like this below code

```
describe('text change test', function() {
  it('The text of .some-span should change when button is clicked', function() {
    assert.equal('Original Text', $('.some-span').text());
    $('.js-click-me').click().then(function(){
         assert.equal('changed text', $('.some-span').text());
     });       
  });
});
```

Comment: .then() only works for functions that return a promise and I don't think click does. Could be wrong though.